# How to make anchor move with respect to a block dragged in jsplumb?

Tags: drag-and-drop, jsplumb

I am trying to build a flowchart using drag and drop options. The user should be able to drag an element from one div and drop it to another.

Now I'm able to drag and drop. I have given an option such that on dropping the block, anchors should appear on them. And I'm able to link these blocks with connectors using js plumb.

I have given the draggable option for dropped blocks. The problem is whenever I drag connected blocks, the anchors' position does not change.

How to make a change such that whenever I drag any block, its anchor and connecting lines should also drag?

Here's my code:
jsPlumb.ready(function() {

```
var EndpointOptions = {
    setDragAllowedWhenFull: true,
    endpoint: "Dot",
    maxConnections: 10,

    paintStyle: {
        width: 21,
        height: 21,
        fillStyle: '#666',

    },
    isSource: true,
    connectorStyle: {
        strokeStyle: "#666"
    },
    isTarget: true,
    dropOptions: {
        drop: function(e, ui) {
            alert('drop!');
        }
    }


};



var count = 0;
var x = "";
//Make element draggable
$(".drag").draggable({
    helper: 'clone',
    cursor: 'move',
    tolerance: 'fit',
    revert: true
});

$(".droppable").droppable({
    accept: '.drag',
    activeClass: "drop-area",
    <!--  stop: function( event, ui ) {}, -->
    drop: function(e, ui) {
        if ($(ui.draggable)[0].id !== "") {


            x = ui.helper.clone();
            console.log("x" + JSON.stringify(x));
            ui.helper.remove();
            x.draggable({
                helper: 'original',
                cursor: 'move',
                containment: '.droppable',
                tolerance: 'fit',

                drop: function(event, ui) {
                    $(ui.draggable).remove();


                }
            });


            x.appendTo('.droppable');


            x.addClass('clg');
            $(".clg").each(function() {

                //alert("hello");
                jsPlumb.addEndpoint($(this), EndpointOptions);

            });

        }

        <!-- $(".clg").dblclick(function() { -->

        <!-- //alert("hello"); -->
        <!-- jsPlumb.addEndpoint($(this), EndpointOptions); -->

        <!-- });     -->
        jsPlumb.bind('connection', function(e) {
            jsPlumb.select(e).addOverlay(["Arrow", {
                foldback: 0.2,
                location: 0.65,
                width: 25
            }]);
        });
        console.log("out x" + JSON.stringify(x));

    }

});
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this jsPlumb.repaintEverything();

Comment: Thanks. But while dragging the block, can't we drag endpoints?

Comment: You should be able to, I use only this when creating a new block  
      jsPlumb.draggable(id, {
        containment: true
    }); so you might want to play around until it works

Answer (score 0):

Here I'm generating an id for each block and adding endpoints based upon respective id.
Here is my changes:

```
if(null == ui.draggable.attr('id')){
            if( ui.draggable.attr('class').indexOf('rule') != -1){
                clone.attr('id', 'rule_' + i);
                jsPlumb.addEndpoint(clone,{anchors: ["Left"]}, EndpointOptions);
            } else {
                clone.attr('id', 'event_' + i);
                jsPlumb.addEndpoint(clone, {anchors: ["Left"]}, EndpointOptions);
            }
i++;
```